# why is exported net device xmit call causing kernel crash?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a modified net device driver exporting its' xmit function. The function is exposed to another stand alone driver. Every time I call the device xmit function from stand alone module, the kernel crashes. There are debug prints before the xmit call but they never showed up.

Here is how I implemented things now.

Community header:

```
struct net_dev_op {
    netdev_tx_t (*xmit) (struct sk_buff * skb, struct net_device * dev);
};
```

In net device driver:

```
static const struct net_dev_op op = {
    .xmit = dev_xmit;
};

stand_alone_module_register(op);
```

In stand alone module:

```
static const struct net_dev_op *ops;

int stand_alone_module_register(static const struct net_dev_op op) {
    ops = &op;
}

static int someFun() {
    ... // code reading ethernet header and manipulating skb
    ops->xmit(skb, dev);  // <-- this is where it crashes
    ...
}
```

In the above code, kernel crashes on call to ops->xmit function. I have verified pointer addresses for the xmit function, ops structure, skb buffer and dev device pointer. None of them is NULL. Yet, the kernel crashes as if it encountered a NULL pointer somewhere.

So why this behavior? Is there any specific function I need to call before calling device specific xmit functions? In the linux kernel, how is the net device xmit function processed? Anyone have any idea where to find the original code? I'm currently developing on Ubuntu server 14.04 LTS with 3.13.0-43, though I seriously doubt this is a kernel version specific thing.

Comment: Show the code before `ops->xmit(skb, dev)` in `someFun()`

Comment: Just manipulation of skb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing a structure on the stack to the register function, which is then storing a pointer to it (the copy on the stack). As soon as you return from the register function, the structure on the stack is destroyed. Then later you try to call a function via the now-reused space on the stack.

stand_alone_module_register ought to accept a *pointer* to a a structure (and the caller should pass the address of its structure). Then it's fine to store the pointer for later use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was suspecting this being the case. This is properly fixed with the proposed changes.